# Read JSON response in Python

Tags: json, python-2.7, selenium

I am trying to read json response from this [link](https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v3beta1/mobileReady?key=AIzaSyDkEX-f1JNLQLC164SZaobALqFv4PHV-kA&screenshot=true&snapshots=true&locale=en_US&url=https://www.economicalinsurance.com/en/&strategy=mobile&filter_third_party_resources=false&callback=_callbacks_._DElanZU7Xh1K). But its not working! I get the following error:

> ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded.

Here is the code I've tried:

```
import urllib2, json
a = urllib2.urlopen('https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v3beta1/mobileReady?key=AIzaSyDkEX-f1JNLQLC164SZaobALqFv4PHV-kA&screenshot=true&snapshots=true&locale=en_US&url=https://www.economicalinsurance.com/en/&strategy=mobile&filter_third_party_resources=false&callback=_callbacks_._DElanZU7Xh1K')
data = json.loads(a)
```

I made these changes:

```
import requests, json
r=requests.get('https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v3beta1/mobileReady?key=AIzaSyDkEX-f1JNLQLC164SZaobALqFv4PHV-kA&screenshot=true&snapshots=true&locale=en_US&url=https://www.economicalinsurance.com/en/&strategy=mobile&filter_third_party_resources=false')
json_data = json.loads(r.text)
print json_data['ruleGroups']['USABILITY']['score']
```

A Quick question - Construct Image link .

I able to get here : -

```
from selenium import webdriver

txt = json_data['screenshot']['data']
txt = str(txt).replace('-','/').replace('_','/')
#then in order to construct the image link i tried : -
image_link = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,'+txt
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(image_link)
```

The problem is i am not getting the image, also the len(object_original) as compared len(image_link) differs . Could anybody please advise the right elements missing in my constructed image link ?. Thank you

Here is API link - https://www.google.co.uk/webmasters/tools/mobile-friendly/ Sorry added it late .

Comment: I assume the server returns JSONP because of `callback=_callbacks_._DElanZU7Xh1K`. Remove it and it will likely return JSON.

Comment: did you have a look at the type and the format of `a`?

Comment: Can you see if this works: `data = json.loads(a.read())`

Comment: Thanks felix-kling , removing the 'callback' parameter from url solved my problem , I will modify the requests parameter

import requests, json
r = requests.get('https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v3beta1/mobileReady?key=AIzaSyDkEX-f1JNLQLC164SZaobALqFv4PHV-kA&screenshot=true&snapshots=true&locale=en_US&url=https://www.economicalinsurance.com/en/&strategy=mobile&filter_third_party_resources=false')
json_data = json.loads(r.text)
print json_data['ruleGroups']['USABILITY']['score']

Could add your answer below, i will accept it now .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two corrections need to be made to your code:

1. The url was corrected (as mentioned by Felix Kling [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33282067/read-json-respone-in-python/33282253#comment54364467_33282067)). You have to remove the `callback` parameter from the GET request you were sending.
2. Also, if you check the type of the response that you were fetching earlier you'll notice that it wasn't a string. It was `<type 'instance'>`. And since `json.loads()` accepts a `string` as a parameter variable you would've got another error. Therefore, use `a.read()` to fetch the response data in `string`.

Hence, this should be your code:

```
import urllib2, json
a = urllib2.urlopen('https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v3beta1/mobileReady?key=AIzaSyDkEX-f1JNLQLC164SZaobALqFv4PHV-kA&screenshot=true&snapshots=true&locale=en_US&url=https://www.economicalinsurance.com/en/&strategy=mobile&filter_third_party_resources=false')
data = json.loads(a.read())
```

Answer to your **second** query (regarding the image) is:

```
from base64 import decodestring

arr = json_data['screenshot']['data']
arr = arr.replace("_", "/")
arr = arr.replace("-","+")

fh = open("imageToSave.jpeg", "wb")
fh.write(str(arr).decode('base64'))
fh.close()
```

Here, is the image you were trying to fetch - [Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxcEO.jpg)

Comment: hey Jason, That was amazing . i will change the "imageToSave.jpeg" string to list elements to iterate over a list of domains. Thanks

Comment: Awesome. Next time if you have another query please post it as a separate question especially if the second query has no correlation to the first query. Anyways, Enjoy! :)

Comment: You are a life saver man , Could you please help me on this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33304357/write-json-elements-to-csv-file-python

Comment: Will have a look into it.

Comment: Okay. Do notify me like this if you have any other issue.

Comment: @ShekharSamanta - Sorry, I'm not familiar with tkinter. But will have a look though.

Answer (score 0):

Felix Kling is right about the address, but I also created a variable that holds the URL. You can try this out to and it should work:

```
import urllib2, json
url = "https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v3beta1/mobileReady?key=AIzaSyDkEX-f1JNLQLC164SZaobALqFv4PHV-kA&screenshot=true&snapshots=true&locale=en_US&url=https://www.economicalinsurance.com/en/&strategy=mobile&filter_third_party_resources=false"
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
data = json.loads(response.read())
print data
```