# Write JSON elements to csv file python

Tags: python, arrays, json, csv, object

I just created a python program which scrapes google webmaster API to check if the target_site is mobile friendly or not & then based on response it extracts certain Json elements. Also it captures the screenshot on local folder

the script is working fine,BUT When i am trying to write those json objects to csv file ,its not working .

Here is my code :-

```
import requests, json, string, random, time
import csv
from base64 import decodestring
from random import randint

#links = open(r'D:\\Carlos\\Links.txt')
links = ['https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v3beta1/mobileReady?key=AIzaSyDkEX-f1JNLQLC164SZaobALqFv4PHV-kA&screenshot=true&snapshots=true&locale=en_US&url=https://www.economicalinsurance.com/en/&strategy=mobile&filter_third_party_resources=false',
         'https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v3beta1/mobileReady?key=AIzaSyDkEX-f1JNLQLC164SZaobALqFv4PHV-kA&screenshot=true&snapshots=true&locale=en_US&url=http://www.volkswagen-me.com/en-vwme/service/protection/motor-insurance.html&strategy=mobile&filter_third_party_resources=false']

def id_generator(size=6, chars=string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits):
    return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(size))

i = 12

def get_data(each):
    try:
        r = requests.get(each)
    except:
        pass
    #time.sleep(randint(1, 3))
    try:    
        json_data = json.loads(r.text)
    except:
        pass
    try:
        score = json_data['ruleGroups']['USABILITY']['score'];score=int(score)
    except:
        pass
    try:
        Pass = json_data['ruleGroups']['USABILITY']['pass'];Pass=str(Pass)
    except:
        pass
    try:
        ConfigureViewport = json_data['formattedResults']['ruleResults']['ConfigureViewport']['localizedRuleName'];ConfigureViewport=str(ConfigureViewport)
    except:
        pass
    try:
        UseLegibleFontSizes = json_data['formattedResults']['ruleResults']['UseLegibleFontSizes']['localizedRuleName'];UseLegibleFontSizes=str(UseLegibleFontSizes)
    except:
        pass
    try:
        AvoidPlugins = json_data['formattedResults']['ruleResults']['AvoidPlugins']['localizedRuleName'];AvoidPlugins=str(AvoidPlugins)
    except:
        pass
    try:
        SizeContentToViewport = json_data['formattedResults']['ruleResults']['SizeContentToViewport']['localizedRuleName'];SizeContentToViewport=str(SizeContentToViewport)
    except:
        pass
    try:
        SizeTapTargetsAppropriately = json_data['formattedResults']['ruleResults']['SizeTapTargetsAppropriately']['localizedRuleName'];SizeTapTargetsAppropriately=str(SizeTapTargetsAppropriately)
    except:
        pass
    try:
        AvoidInterstitials = json_data['formattedResults']['ruleResults']['AvoidInterstitials']['localizedRuleName'];AvoidInterstitials=str(AvoidInterstitials)
    except:
        pass
    try:
        image_link = json_data['screenshot']['data']; image_link = image_link.replace("_", "/").replace("-","+")
    except:
        pass
    #try:
    id_generator_name = "".join( [random.choice(string.letters) for i in xrange(15)] )+'.jpeg'
    #except:
       # pass
    #try:
    fh = open(id_generator_name, "wb")
    #except:
    #    pass
    try:
        fh.write(str(image_link).decode('base64'))
        time.sleep(1)
    except:
        pass
    try:
        fh.close()
    except:
        pass
    try:
        error_code = json_data['error']['message'];error_code=str(error_code)
    except:
        pass
    try:
        print each, score, Pass, ConfigureViewport, UseLegibleFontSizes, AvoidPlugins, SizeContentToViewport, SizeTapTargetsAppropriately, AvoidInterstitials, error_code
    except:
        pass
    try:
        writer.writerow({'each':each, 'score':score, 'Pass':Pass, 'ConfigureViewport':ConfigureViewport,
                         'UseLegibleFontSizes':UseLegibleFontSizes, 'AvoidPlugins':AvoidPlugins,
                         'SizeContentToViewport':SizeContentToViewport,'SizeTapTargetsAppropriately':SizeTapTargetsAppropriately,
                         'AvoidInterstitials':AvoidInterstitials, 'error_code':error_code,'imagename':id_generator_name})
    except:
        pass

#path to the csv file
with open("D:\Carlos\Data_file\output.csv", "ab")as export:
    fieldnames = ['each', 'score', 'Pass', 'ConfigureViewport', 'UseLegibleFontSizes', 'AvoidPlugins', 'SizeContentToViewport',
                  'SizeTapTargetsAppropriately', 'AvoidInterstitials', 'error_code','imagename']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(export, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    for each in links:
    #try:
        get_data(each)
    #except:
    #  pass
```

Please advice on how to write to csv ? Or where things are wrong in the code ?

Comment: Why would you want to put *JSON* data in a *CSV* file?

Comment: There are almost 1000 links , & for each of them i want to get those JSON data in csv for analysis & comparison purpose .

Comment: That doesn't really explain *why* - JSON is a more structured data representation than CSV, so will probably be *easier* to manipulate and analyse.

Comment: What do you mean by "its not working"? Corn pops? Also, please provide a [mcve] to focus on the problem. Your code is a bit.. messy.. right now...

Comment: I am more comfortable to work with CSV , As you can see in the above code , I able to assign variables to each of those JSON elements i want to parse , but when i try to write those variables into a csv file , it does not write anything & code exits with no errors .

Comment: Well you catch every possible exception for each ``try: except:`` block so it is understandable that no error is shown. You should catch explicit exceptions to not hide the unexpected ones.

Comment: Basically i want to iterate over a list of 1000 domains , i.e. query each of them to google webmaster api. Now the response possibility is 3 types of JSON response . [pass, fail, error]

Therefore i had included try: except: pass , on each of the local variables assignment inside the function . The code successfully prints the variables on shell , but it doesn't write to the csv file ,

Comment: Please explain what *is not working*. And it could be useful to add a debugging print in your script to show the dict your are passing to `writer.writerow` (`print ({'each':each, 'score':score, ...})`)

Comment: *"where things are wrong in the code ?"* - your error handling is, not to put too fine a point on it, completely useless. Please read http://blog.codekills.net/2011/09/29/the-evils-of--except--/ and understand that the code as written is impossible to debug.

Comment: Please try your code with no ``try: except:`` blocks, you will understand what's going on.

Comment: I got the error , Dict was not allowing 'error_code' str variable as "" , i added if else 
error_code = ''
    try:
        error_code = json_data['error']['message'];error_code=str(error_code)
    except:
        pass
    if error_code == '':
        error_code = 'remove_later'

Answer (score 2):

I like to use Pandas dataframes for this, but it may be overkill if you wouldn't use Pandas otherwise. Pandas dataframes are also great for analysis and comparison.

You would put the JSON into a dataframe, and then output the dataframe to a CSV file.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_json('path/to/json/file')
df.to_csv('filename.csv')
```

Note that it's this simple only when your JSON has one level and might as well be a csv. Otherwise, you would need to read the JSON into a dict, navigate to the appropriate level and then read that into a dataframe.

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_json.html
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html

http://pandas.pydata.org/