# Read json url in makemytrip site using python

Tags: python, json

I am new to this  and I am working on a project, where i have to get 
hotel rate and room type from makemytrip.com

1 step  - I search Octave hotel in Banglore( India ) in makemytrip.com
2 step  - I inspect the browser for json file where i can get the data

I got this url [json type url link](https://hotelz.makemytrip.com/makemytrip/site/hotels/detailJsonData?ajaxCall=T&session_cId=1466139781139&city=BLR&country=IN&checkin=06302016&checkout=08072016&searchText=null&area=&roomStayQualifier=1e0e&hotelId=201503101445304217&i=null)  of Type =application/json which contains data that i wana read  but when i read the url using  this code

```
import requests
r = requests.get('https://hotelz.makemytrip.com/makemytrip/site/hotels/detailJsonData?ajaxCall=T&session_cId=1466139781139&city=BLR&country=IN&checkin=06302016&checkout=08072016&searchText=null&area=&roomStayQualifier=1e0e&hotelId=201503101445304217&i=null')
r.headers['content-type']
```

the type i am getting is text/html instead of application/json

How to read this data ??

Comment: Just use `json` library and something like `json.loads(r.read())`, There's many questions about this around, take a look e.g. to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33282067/read-json-response-in-python

Comment: Are you sure that URL is valid? I get an error page when I visit it using my browser. I suspect the problem is caused by that `session_cId` parameter.

Comment: 1. json.loads not working for me        and    2. well i go through step 1 and step 2 so i got proper session id and link give me json data in new browser tab